# Can't bind to itemprop since it isn't a known property of 'a'

Tags: html, angular, dom

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/itemprop), itemprop is a global attribute and every html element can have this attribute specified.  I would like to bind to this attribute as such:

```
<a [href]="someUrl" [itemprop]="microData"></a>
```

However, it doesn't seem like Angular recognizes this as a native attribute.  What am I missing? The alternative I have in mind is to create a directive that will add this attribute onto the element.

Comment: Try using `[attr.itemprop]="microData"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding using `attr` like this -

```
<a [href]="someUrl" [attr.itemprop]="microData"></a>
```

Angular by default uses property binding but `itemprop` is not a property of a. To tell Angular explicitly to use attribute binding like above.